# Set (click) attribute in button using renderer2 in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-renderer2

I am trying to create a chat-based application where I am creating each type of chat popup according to requirements and using `Angular Renderer2`. I tried to add a `(click)` attribute to the chat message element while rendering that in UI.

I got this error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element':
> '((click))' is not a valid attribute name.

chat.component.ts

```js
const btn3: HTMLDivElement = this.renderer.createElement('button');
this.renderer.addClass(btn3, 'btn');
this.renderer.addClass(btn3, 'btn-light');
this.renderer.setAttribute(btn3, '(click)', 'sendMessage()');
btn3.innerHTML = 'Maybe later!';
this.renderer.appendChild(buttons, btn3);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAttribute` function is to set the element's attributes like `disabled`. Instead you could use the [`listen()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen) function to add an event listener.

```js
this.renderer.listen(
  btn3, 
  'click', 
  this.sendMessage.bind(this)
);
```

**OR**

```js
this.renderer.listen(
  btn3, 
  'click', 
  () => this.sendMessage()
);
```

You either need to `bind` or use arrow-functions to preserve the meaning of `this` keyword in the callback function.

Comment: Thanks @michael-d for helping,

Regards, Bharat